# A curve that interpolates the baked keyframes

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, keyframes

I have a baked animation. Is there anyway that I can get a curve with less number of keyframes? So that I can adjust the animation easily.

Comment: hello, what kind of animation? what curve are you talking about, curve in the Graph Editor? maybe tell a bit more...

Comment: Yes the curves in graph editor. Like in a baked animation there is a keyframe on each frame. But what I want is a bezier curve that follows the same path but uses less number of keyframes. Is there a way to do this automatically? I can do this manually by deleting extra keyframes and then assigning bezier interpolation to the remaining keyframes

Comment: With all curves selected and cursor in Graph editor , search for Decimate

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem